# Rails 5 erb doesn't escape html

Tags: xss, erb, ruby-on-rails-5.2

In a rails 5.2.3 erb template:

```
<% input = "<script>alert('XSS')</script>" %>
<p><%= input %></p>
```

is showing `<script>alert('XSS')</script>` instead of &gt.. etc

Isn't <%= ... %> supposed to prevent against reflected xss attack?
Same issue if input is retrieved from params[:input]

The raw  is output in the html:

[image]

Comment: Where is it showing that? In the page as viewed by the user, of course it shows like that. In the source it is encoded to `&lt;` though, so it's not executed.

Comment: I added an image showing it's not escaped in the source html

Comment: Try ctrl-u :) My guess is that inspector is formatting it for you, but it is not colored as a tag, so it's just a text node in the DOM.

Comment: Yep, I see that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Need to look in source ctrl+u
as Gabor suggested